# Is it possible to connect PHP PDO to remote MySQL with SSL but without client certificate

Tags: php, pdo

If i understand this correctly remote MySQL server has server certificate to authenticate to a client and encrypt the connection.
And client can have client certificate to authenticate to the server, but if i do not need to authenticate client to the server, because i only need encryption, can i omit client certificate when crating PDO connection.

And what is the syntax for that, for example 
$con = new PDO('mysql:host=someHost;dbname=someDB;port=3306',$user,$pass);
Where to specify that i want SSL but without client certificate

Comment: So the SSL endpoint, the MySQL server, does not have the certificate?

Comment: you need a client certificate, but they are freely avalable

Comment: `$options = array(
 PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8',
 PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => '/path/to/cacert.pem',` ... `$con = new PDO(' .. $options)`

Comment: @Jay, the endpoint MySQL Server has certificate, but I the client with PDO does not have certificate. That file that tim specified  '/path/to/cacert.pem' in a command is what i do not have. Is that necessary, i read somewhere that "Client certificates are not required unless you set the REQUIRE X509 option for the account"

Comment: Why do you think that you need a client certificate? What happens if you just try and see how that could work out?

Comment: I was told that i need to connect using SSL, i have try a "regular" PDO connection, like $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=MyServer;dbname=DbName', 
               $user, 
               $pass
              ); But it throws Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user

Comment: That's because the user you supplied doesn't have access. Does it say `Access denied for user something@localhost`?

Comment: Here’s an example - https://www.amplitudedesign.com/2018/11/remote-mysql-ssl-connections-using-php-mysqli-and-pdo/

Comment: @user9189147 i alreafy read that, and there is example with client certificates it iven says in coment "//ALL PEM FILES ARE COPIED FROM THE REMOTE MYSQL SERVER AND CREATED WITH OPENSSL" and you se client is using them. I wont to connect with SSL but without certificate files on client, is that posible with MySQL

Comment: I’d personally use remote SSH tunneling. This method provides for much more throughput. Set it up with autossh using tunneling. Autossh runs as a daemon in the background. See - https://www.amplitudedesign.com/2018/11/connecting-to-mysql-remotely-using-autossh-and-ssh-tunneling/

Comment: tenx user9189147 it looks interesting I will check it

Answer (score 0):

Download certificate from

wget --no-check-certificate https://dl.cacerts.digicert.com/DigiCertGlobalRootCA.crt.pem

pdo connection code looks like

```
    $options = array(
   PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => '/path to crt file /DigiCertGlobalRootCA.crt.pem',
   PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT => false
);
$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;port=$port;dbname=$db_name";

try {
     $pdo = new \PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
} catch (\PDOException $e) {
     throw new \PDOException($e->getMessage(), (int)$e->getCode());
}
```

mysql connection looks like

```
//Initializes MySQLi
$conn = mysqli_init();

mysqli_ssl_set($conn,NULL,NULL, "/path to crt file /DigiCertGlobalRootCA.crt.pem", NULL, NULL);
mysqli_real_connect($conn, $host, $username, $password, $db_name, $port, NULL, MYSQLI_CLIENT_SSL_DONT_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT);

//OR//
mysqli_real_connect($conn, $host, $username, $password, $db_name, 3306, NULL, MYSQLI_CLIENT_SSL);


//If connection failed, show the error
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    die('Failed to connect to MySQL: '.mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

This is how i managed to conect with PDO

```
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=myServer;dbname=MyDb',
                $user,
                $pass,
                array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA     => '/etc/ssl/certs/anyOneOfTheMilionCertsFromHere.pem',
                      PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CAPATH => '/etc/ssl/certs/')
              );
```

I do not know whay but it does not work if i do not specify .pem file in "PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA", it can be any .pem file for example Deutsche_Telekom_Root_CA_2.pem, Baltimore_CyberTrust_Root.pem, ... it will work.

And this is how i managed to do it with the MYSQLI, 
just elegantly telling it that i whant SSL with constant "MYSQLI_CLIENT_SSL", without specifying some random friking .pem file

```
$mi = mysqli_init();
$conn = mysqli_real_connect($mi, $server, $user, $pass, $db, 3306, NULL, MYSQLI_CLIENT_SSL) or die(mysqli_connect_error());
```

Can this be done with PDO(like normaly) without explicitly specifying .pem file?

Comment: Are you sure that mysqli example is indeed connected through SSL or did it fall back to non-SSL connection? I tried that way but `SHOW STATUS LIKE 'Ssl_cipher'` in PHP returns empty string - so it is not actually connected through SSL; while in mysql commandline the Ssl_cipher returns `DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256` as expected.